# IIS сквозная AD аутентификация без запроса логина и пароля .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

Что сделано:

1. приложение на .NET 5.0.
   Включена аутентификация:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.Negotiate)
```

Пробовал

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

Получаем в результате ввода логина и пароля в браузере аутентификацию на серваке:

```
"name": "LOCALAD0\\WebTest",
"authenticationType": "Negotiate",
"isAuthenticated": true,
```

2. в IIS включена ТОЛЬКО "проверка подлинности Windows".
   Так же пробовал прописывать в web.config

```
       system.web
         authentication mode="Windows"
         identity impersonate="true"
         authorization
           allow users="*"
         authorization
       system.web
```

Прочитал и перепробывал:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770347/On-Premise-Application-Identity-Windows-Authentica
- https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Подскажите каким образом на IIS подключить сквозную аутентификацию **БЕЗ** запроса логина и пароля от Active Directory из браузера?
ПК находится в домене, пользователь авторизован под доменной учеткой - НО при входе на сайт все равно в браузере появляется окно запроса логина и пароля. Вводишь данные из AD - аутентификация пройдена. Как избавиться от запроса и чтоб подхватывало от ОС Windows?

Comment: Вот это https://levelup.gitconnected.com/about-integrated-windows-authentication-and-how-to-implement-it-in-asp-net-core-running-on-iis-369177dff798 пробовали?

Comment: @4per вроде делал как написано.
"Установите для < WindowsAuthentication> значение true в applicationhost.config, который находится под. vs" - это ведь для IIS Express. У меня на локальном компе заходит без запроса логина и пароля. Но когда сайт публикуется в IIS где есть домен, и пользователь из домена этого же пытается зайти на сайт (даже непосредственно на самом сервере) - требует логин и пароль ввести, не подхватывает аутентификацию ОС.
Может стоит уточнить что приложение WebApi, создавалось по умолчанию с включенной аутентификацией ОС.

Comment: @4per по поводу "Установите для < WindowsAuthentication> значение true" полагаю в IIS нормальном в настройках выставляется это как аутентификация Windwos и поставщики соответствующие. Не помогло. Явно где-то руки кривят... узнать бы где...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение прблемы. Таилась она не в IIS и не в коде - они были настроены как в перечисленных в вопросе статьях (и комментарии в т.ч.).

Решение - в настройках и запретах политик барузера, тут: https://community.terrasoft.ru/articles/kak-resit-vopros-s-otobrazeniem-okna-domennoi-avtorizacii-pri-nastroike-autentifikacii

Полагаю существуют способы групповых политик, чтобы не настраивать на каждом клиенте домена. Можно выдохнуть...